# Connecting to password protected AFP server from terminal?

Tags: network, password, mount, file-sharing, afp

I have one Mac set up with file sharing on the desktop, and I am trying to connect to it from my other Mac from the Terminal.  I made a folder *mount* in */Volumes/*, then I used the following command.

```
sudo mount -t afp afp://user:pass@ipaddress/Desktop /Volumes/mount
```

(obviously I changed the user/pass/ip to the correct information)

Though whenever I try to access it, it says I do not have permission.  When I access it through Finder with the same username and password, it works perfectly fine.

<del>Is there any reason this is not working?</del>

**Edit** - If I run the `ls` command with `sudo` I can access the files.  So update to the question:

Is there a way to change the ownership of the Volume? `chown` is throwing the error `Operation not permitted`, even with `sudo`.

Comment: Clarification requested- if you can access the remote share using Finder, can you not drag the mounted volume into a terminal window after typing in "cd " instead of trying to mount it directly?

Comment: @KarlC When I get bored, I try various things.  For example this time I was going to make a web-based file explorer on my local computer to access file shares on my network.  This can easily be done with PHP and the right permissions, but to do that I need to be able to mount the Volume via the Terminal.  I Googled it and only found the above code.  It mounts the Volume properly, but when I go to open the Volume it just says that I do not have permission to view the contents of the Volume.

Comment: @klanomath if I use the `sudo` it mounts (unreadable but it mounts).  If I remove it I get the following error: `mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error 1, errno is 1`.

Comment: @klanomath The "server" mac is 10.10.5, the mac I am using is 10.11.3.

Answer (score 3):

To mount a share in Terminal use the following commands:

```
mkdir /Volumes/mount
mount -t afp afp://user:pass@ipaddress/Desktop /Volumes/mount
```

This works because the folder /Volumes is world read & writable.

If you use `sudo mkdir /Volumes/mount` *mount* has the following permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 root  admin  -       68  8 Mär 02:40 . <- mount
drwxrwxrwt@ 5 root  admin  hidden 170  8 Mär 02:40 .. <- /Volumes
```

and the only possible command to mount a share is:

```
sudo mount -t afp afp://user:pass@ipaddress/Desktop /Volumes/mount
```

because you are not allowed to "write" (=mount) to the folder *mount* as non-root user.

with the following result:

```
drwx------  1 root  wheel  -        264  8 Mär 02:38 . <- mount (the share "Desktop")
drwxrwxrwt@ 5 root  admin  hidden   170  8 Mär 02:42 .. <- /Volumes
```

and you can't even open (=read) the folder with your user.

If you create the mount folder with `mkdir /Volumes/mount` the permissions looks like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 user  admin  -       68  8 Mär 02:42 . <- mount
drwxrwxrwt@ 5 root  admin  hidden 170  8 Mär 02:42 .. <- /Volumes
```

After mounting the share with:

```
mount -t afp afp://user:pass@ipaddress/Desktop /Volumes/mount
```

the permissions look like this:

```
drwx------  1 user  staff  -        264  8 Mär 02:38 . <- mount (the share "Desktop")
drwxrwxrwt@ 5 root  admin  hidden   170  8 Mär 02:42 .. <- /Volumes
```

Comment: Missing step is `sudo chown $(whoami) /Volumes/mount` after `sudo mkdir`. `/Volumes` is not world read and writable on mine.